# How to Store and Retrieve Data in Multidimensional Array in Angular4 / Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to store some values in Angular 4 (Ionic 3) and then fetch a row from the array based on a key. The key is passed into a function and the function retrieves the values with which to compute the values. The class property is below. I am pretty sure it is formatted right.

```
let chemicals = [{
    "trichlor" : [{
        "ozmul": 6854.95, 
        "volume": "x"
    }],
    "dichlor": [{
        "ozmul": 4149.03, 
        "volume": 0.9351
    }],
    "cal-hypo-48": [{
        "ozmul": 3565.44,
        "volume": 0.9352
    }],
    "cal-hypo-53": [{
        "ozmul": 3936.84,
        "volume": 0.9352
    }],
    "cal-hypo-65": [{
        "ozmul": 4828.12,
        "volume": 0.9352
    }],
    "cal-hypo-73": [{
        "ozmul": 5422.41,
        "volume": 0.9352
    }],
    "lithium-hypo": [{
        "ozmul": 2637.5,
        "volume": 0.978
    }],
    "chlorine-gas": [{
        "ozmul": 7489.4,
        "volume": "x"
    }]
}];
```

So basically, what I need to do is grab a value passed into a function (let's use trichlor for an example). I then need to be able to use that value to fetch the ozmul and volume values associated with trichlor. What is the proper way to accomplish this within a provider? Below is an example of code from the function that uses the values:

```
chemical = "trichlor"; // This is passed into the function

if (chemicals.chemical.ozmul == 'x') {
    let tempValueTwoWeight = 'Unknown';
} else {
    let tempValueTwoVolume = (tempValueTwo * chemicals.chemical.volume)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this will also suit you and you will not need to hardcode paths

```
test(val:string){
  this.chemicals.forEach(data => {
    let value = data[val].find(data => data.volume === 'x');
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

Have this as a method pass the val you want to search and also the data.volume parameter can be made dynamic and check

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
chemicals[0][chemical][0].ozmul
```

In-place of `chemicals.chemical.ozmul`